# How to split data using either R or Python or Excel, such that they spread horizontally after every nth row?

Tags: python, r, excel

I want to achieve the below Output based on the below Input. The Question is for a larger data set(>100k).

```
Input file:
AB1
AB2
AB3
AB4
AB5
AB6
AB7
AB8
AB9
AB10

Output File:(After Every 2 rows)
AB1 AB2
AB3 AB4
AB5 AB6
AB7 AB8
AB9 AB10
```

[image]

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to put this. If you know how to solve, kindly guide me in that direction at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
Input = c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "AB8", "AB9", "AB10")

cbind(Input[seq(1,length(Input),2)],
    Input[seq(2,length(Input),2)])

     [,1]  [,2]  
[1,] "AB1" "AB2" 
[2,] "AB3" "AB4" 
[3,] "AB5" "AB6" 
[4,] "AB7" "AB8" 
[5,] "AB9" "AB10"
```

Comment: its also `matrix(input, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this `base R` solution. You can create an index every two rows with `rep()` and then use `unstack()` to get the desired output. I used the data you shared as `df`. Here the code:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", 
"AB7", "AB8", "AB9", "AB10")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
#Create an index
df$index <- paste0('V',rep(1:2,length.out=nrow(df)))
#Reshape
df2 <- unstack(df)
```

Output:

```
   V1   V2
1 AB1  AB2
2 AB3  AB4
3 AB5  AB6
4 AB7  AB8
5 AB9 AB10
```